# Unchecked Overriding when defining a base mapper for mybatis?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ibatis, mybatis

I'm trying to define a base mapper interface for MyBatis. I've tried this:

```
public interface IMapper<T> {
    <T> T select(int id);
}

public interface FooMapper extends IMapper<Foo>{
    @Override
    @Select("SELECT * FROM foos WHERE id = {#id}")
    Foo select(int id);
}
```

But I'm getting Unchecked Overriding warnings from IntelliJ. Should I disable them, or am I really doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the extra `<T>` on the select method so it is:

```
interface IMapper<T> {
    T select(int id);
}
```